# GitHub Actions workflow fails for iOS Build

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, github-actions

I am trying to set up CI/CD for my React Native App using GitHub actions. I have added Firebase configuration files for my project as GitHub Secrets. The iOS build workflow fails with the following error log.

```
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3073900Z ** BUILD FAILED **
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3075130Z 
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3075970Z 
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3077170Z The following build commands failed:
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3081040Z    CopyPlistFile /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TLS-dlqmcvmjotwzuugkybwxlhjuzmzz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TLS.app/GoogleService-Info.plist /Users/runner/work/ALT/ALT/App/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3086250Z (1 failure)
2021-10-05T12:43:48.3584560Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 65.
```

I have tried changing the target path of the GoogleService-Info.plist but the same error persists. The workflow file can be found [here](https://github.com/Active-Learning-and-Teaching/ALT/blob/ios-workflow/.github/workflows/ios_flow.yml). Any insights into this would be helpful.

Comment: Here's an example https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/.github/workflows/storage.yml#L30

Comment: Having the same issue, but the file is copied while building... Happens in other virtualized services as well.